# ASP.NET Core Identity User logged out randomly after a few minutes. But not on Localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

*****Whenever I am on localhost, everything works perfectly.** Once I publish to the webserver***, a user will only be able to stay logged in after a few minutes sometimes even less with little to no consistency.

Here is my `Startup.cs.ConfigureServices`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // MVC Shit 

    services.AddControllers(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);

    // DBContext shit
    services.AddDbContextPool<ventsus7_InventoryContext>(options => 
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddScoped<IIMS, IMSSQL>();

    services.AddDbContext<EcommerceWebsiteContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    // Identity shit
    services.AddIdentity<EcommerceWebsiteUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
    {
        config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    })
        .AddDefaultUI()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<EcommerceWebsiteContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddAuthentication();
    services.AddAuthorization();

    // Cache
    services.AddMemoryCache();

    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        //options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(10);
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    });


    // Payments Stuff
    StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = Configuration.GetSection("Stripe")["SecretKey"];
}
```

This is the `Startup.cs.Configure`:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    //app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseSession();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

I really don't even know where to start looking. Any help would be great.

Update:
I was asked to find the bearer token, however, I don't see one. Below is a screenshot of what I found. (Please keep in mind, I don't know what any of these are or how this all works)
[image]

Comment: If you put the bearer token into a jwt decoder (try jwt.ms), what is the expiration?  is it very short?

Comment: I just added what I found where I believe is where the bearer token should be. It seems to not be there. any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: You can find your bearer token attached to each http request. Open the Network tab, select a row, open the request header. You will then find the authorization field. You might have to reload the page

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but I don't see anything. Use this login at shop.vents-us.com and see if you see it. testing@shop.vents-us.com HelloWorld1!

Comment: I'm unable to login with those credentials "Your email needs to be validated before login.".  I think you may be looking in the wrong place for the bearer token.  Once you have logged in, select the Network tab instead, and look at the Headers section, for a header called Authorization.  This should start with 'BEARER'

Comment: I just validated the login, I'm looking, and you may be right, but I still don't see anything.

Comment: Do you think it is possible this is a part of my problem?